# Datatables toggle with checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am struggling with a feature where I would like to switch datatables on/off with a checkbox using jQuery.

It actually works if I have no datatable defined, then I turn it on/off without problems.

But I would like for the datatable to be on by default and only then to turn it off and back on. I am getting reinitialize warnings.

I have something like this:

```
$('#datatable-switch').on('click',function(){

  if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 0) {

    $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1);
    showLockersDataTable();

  } else {

    $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
    lockersTable.DataTable().destroy();
  }

});
```

Comment: DataTables [can't be initiated twice](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3), which might cause your problem.

Comment: @Tarekis according to the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#destroy) you can use `destroy()` to destroy an old table before re-initializing a new one.

Comment: can you show your first initialization?? where is showLockersDataTable??

Comment: Try initializing, destroying, then re-initializing DataTables right away without the checkbox, just to remove that element from the equation.

Comment: @MattK yes, i figured that out now, i was thinking it would automatically rei-initiate on `DataTable()` wherer `destroy()` was used with it or not, and so count as re-initation, because in the [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/3#destroy) you linked the `DataTable` is stored to a variable and `destroy()` is used on the variable rather than using `DataTable()` again. But it works just the same way, as you can see in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/tqqjv2hx/2/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really seems like no problem. You might have messed something up with your

```
showLockersDataTable();
```

and

```
lockersTable.DataTable().destroy();
```

i cannot analyze as you didn't provide neither `showLockersDataTable()` nor `lockersTable`.

But you have to simply solve it like this:

```
// Get the jQuery Object for your DataTable
var example =  $('#example');

// Bind listener on the checkbox 
$('#datatable-switch').on('click',function(){

if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 0) {

      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1);
      showDataTable(example);

    }
    else {

      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
      hideDataTable(example);
    }
});
```

where the two used functions are:

```
// Declare show and hide functions
function showDataTable(dataTable){

  dataTable.DataTable();

}

function hideDataTable(dataTable){

  dataTable.DataTable().destroy();

}
```

Now your listener on `click` is bound and you can initiate on page load.

```
showDataTable();
```

And here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tarekis/tqqjv2hx/3/) on JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly. I was pretty close, had also a problem on checkbox itself (wrong inital data-click-state). Thx again.